# How do I make an ASP.Net GridView postback on an onBlur event?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net GridView, with two columns ("ID" and "name").  The name column is editable via an <asp:TextBox>.  What I want to do is have the grid trigger its update event when the user clicks away from an editable cell.

I know I can attach an onBlur event handler to the TextBox to retrieve the value when the user clicks away.  However, I don't know how to trigger the GridView's update event programmatically through JavaScript.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really want to run the page through a full life-cycle to update a single value?  I would vote for a simple webservice that can take a string and an ID as an argument and update the appropriate record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `TextBox` set `AutoPostBack="True"`. This will cause a postback when the client `change` event fires, which is probably what you want rather than `blur`. Attach a `TextChanged` handler to the textbox and you can call your grid update method from there.

you can get the row index for the textbox that triggered the event like this:

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gridRow = ((GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).NamingContainer);
    Console.WriteLine(gridRow.RowIndex);
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  I was initially worried that autopostback would post-back on every keystroke but MSDN assured me that this wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the submit method for your Form object from the onBlur event.

```
myForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set AutoPostback="True" on your Textbox and in the Codebehind save the new valuein the Event Handler.